# Bigquery Dynamic SQL with referencing table and value

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a scenario where I need to generate dynamic SQL using following two tables:

[image]

[image]

User can add many rows in ref_table. I need to create a following SQL dynamically based on all entries in Ref_table :

```
select sum(case when id=1 then val end)/sum(val) as Red_percent,
    sum(case when id=2 then val end)/sum(val) as Blue_percent,
    sum(case when id=3 then val end)/sum(val) as Green_percent
    from Transaction_table
```

Can anyone please help me to write dynamic sql to generate above sql with all entries in ref_table?

Answer (score 1):

First - I would recommend using different query approach

```
select * from (
  select distinct ref, 
    sum(val) over(partition by ref) / sum(val) over() val
  from ref_table r
  join transaction_table t
  using(id)
)
pivot (min(val) for ref in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'))
```

Secondly, below is the way to generate this based on ref_table content

```
select '''
select * from (
  select distinct ref, 
    sum(val) over(partition by ref) / sum(val) over() val
  from ref_table r
  join transaction_table t
  using(id)
)
pivot (min(val) for ref in (''' || (select string_agg(distinct '"' || ref || '"') from ref_table)  || '''))
'''
```

Finally, you can just execute it as in below example

```
execute immediate '''
select * from (
  select distinct ref, 
    sum(val) over(partition by ref) / sum(val) over() val
  from ref_table r
  join transaction_table t
  using(id)
)
pivot (min(val) for ref in (''' || (select string_agg(distinct '"' || ref || '"') from ref_table)  || '''))
'''
```